# How to access a variable in one function in another function?

Tags: c++, function

I am trying to write a C++ code where the user enters a date and it outputs the day of the week that date lands on using John Conway's Doomsday algorithm.

I am trying to access the variable z which was declared and defined in the function dayofthemonth and use it in the function called dayoftheweek. Please keep in mind that I am very new to C++ so if you can answer as simply as you can, that would help a lot. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;



int dayofthemonth (int year, int month){          
    int z;

    if ((year % 400 == 0 || year % 100 !=0) && (year % 4 == 0)){  //reference day of    the month for leap years
    cout << year << " is a leap year." << endl;  

    if (month == 1){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 4." << endl;
       z = 4;
    }
    if (month == 2){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 1." << endl;
       z = 1;
    } 
    if (month == 3){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 0." << endl;
       z = 0;   
    }
    if (month == 4){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 4." << endl; 
       z = 4;
    }
    if (month == 5){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 9." << endl;
       z = 9;
    }
    if (month == 6){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 6." << endl;
       z = 6;
    }
    if (month == 7){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 11." << endl;
       z = 11;
    }
    if (month == 8){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 8." << endl;
       z = 8;
    }
    if (month == 9){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 5." << endl;
       z = 5;
    }
    if (month == 10){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 10." << endl;
       z = 10;
    }
    if (month == 11){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 7." << endl;
       z = 7;
    }
    if (month == 12){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 12." << endl;  
       z = 12;
    }     

 }

 else{                                                       //reference day of the month for non-leap years
    cout << year << " is not a leap year." << endl;

    if (month == 1){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 3." << endl;
       z = 3;
    }
    if (month == 2){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 0." << endl;
       z = 0;
    }
    if (month == 3){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 0." << endl;
       z = 0;   
    }
    if (month == 4){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 4." << endl; 
       z = 4;
    }
    if (month == 5){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 9." << endl;
       z = 9;
    }
    if (month == 6){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 6." << endl;
       z = 6;
    }
    if (month == 7){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 11." << endl;
       z = 11;
    }
    if (month == 8){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 8." << endl;
       z = 8;
    }
    if (month == 9){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 5." << endl;
       z = 5;
    }
    if (month == 10){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 10." << endl;
       z = 10;
    }
    if (month == 11){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 7." << endl;
       z = 7;
    }
    if (month == 12){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 12." << endl;  
       z = 12;
    }       

 }     



}

int doomsday (int year){         //reference day of the week
  int a, b, c , d, e, x;


  a = ((year/100) % 4);
  b = (year % 100);
  c = (b/12);
  d = (b % 12);
  e = (d/4);

  x = ((c + d + e + (5*a) + 2) % 7);

  if (x == 0){
    cout << "The doomsday for " << year << " is Sunday." << endl;
  }
  else if (x == 1){
    cout << "The doomsday for " << year << " is Monday." << endl;
  }   
  else if (x == 2){
    cout << "The doomsday for " << year << " is Tuesday." << endl;
  }
  else if (x == 3){
    cout << "The doomsday for " << year << " is Wednesday." << endl;
  }
  else if (x == 4){
    cout << "The doomsday for " << year << " is Thursday." << endl;
  }
  else if (x == 5){
    cout << "The doomsday for " << year << " is Friday." << endl;
  }
  else if (x == 6){
    cout << "The doomsday for " << year << " is Saturday." << endl;
  }



}

void dayoftheweek(int month, int day, int year}(

 int r;

 cout << "You want to find out what day of the week " << month << "/" << day << "/" << year << " lies on." << endl;

  doomsday(year);


  r = (day - z) + 14;          //offset between the given day and the result of dayofthemonth function.
  cout << r << endl;


}


int main(){

int year, month, day;    


cout << "Enter the year." << endl;
cin >> year;

cout << "Enter the month using numbers 1-12." << endl;
cin >> month;

cout << "Enter the day." << endl;
cin >> day;

dayoftheweek(month, day, year);



system ("PAUSE");
return 0;


}
```

Comment: int z; is out of scope ... you can't. 
You must change implementation :)

Comment: Why don't you just `return z`?

Answer (score 1):

Your functions have return type `int` but don't actually return any value. Return `z`, then pass it into the next function as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Another observation, This function `int dayofthemonth (int year, int month)` has no caller.

May be you should change as,

`r = (day - z) + 14;` to

`r = (day - dayofthemonth(year, month)) + 14;` //provided this function returns `z`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a simple way to use one variable in all of scopes in your code you can declared it before main function and after " #include <...> "s and "using namespace ...".
but be careful when you use this way because if you use that variable 2 or more time in your code and dont make it 0 you will see wrong answers.
and at last i used "cin.get()" in my code insted of "system("pause")" because if you want to compile your code in linux "system("pause")" will give you an error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int z;

void dayofthemonth (int year, int month)
{

    z = 0;
    if ((year % 400 == 0 || year % 100 !=0) && (year % 4 == 0)){  //reference day of   the month for leap years
    cout << year << " is a leap year." << endl;

    if (month == 1){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 4." << endl;
       z = 4;
    }
    if (month == 2){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 1." << endl;
       z = 1;
    }
    if (month == 3){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 0." << endl;
       z = 0;
    }
    if (month == 4){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 4." << endl;
       z = 4;
    }
    if (month == 5){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 9." << endl;
       z = 9;
    }
    if (month == 6){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 6." << endl;
       z = 6;
    }
    if (month == 7){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 11." << endl;
       z = 11;
    }
    if (month == 8){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 8." << endl;
       z = 8;
    }
        if (month == 9){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 5." << endl;
       z = 5;
    }
    if (month == 10){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 10." << endl;
       z = 10;
    }
    if (month == 11){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 7." << endl;
       z = 7;
    }
    if (month == 12){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 12." << endl;
       z = 12;
    }

 }

 else{                                                       //reference day of the month for non-leap years
    cout << year << " is not a leap year." << endl;

    if (month == 1){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 3." << endl;
       z = 3;
    }
    if(month == 2){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 0." << endl;
   z = 0;
    }
    if (month == 3){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 0." << endl;
       z = 0;
    }
    if (month == 4){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 4." << endl;
       z = 4;
    }
    if (month == 5){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 9." << endl;
       z = 9;
    }
    if (month == 6){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 6." << endl;
       z = 6;
    }
    if (month == 7){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 11." << endl;
       z = 11;
    }
    if (month == 8){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 8." << endl;
       z = 8;
    }
    if (month == 9){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 5." << endl;
       z = 5;
    }
    if (month == 10){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 10." << endl;
       z = 10;
    }
    if (month == 11){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 7." << endl;
       z = 7;
    }
    if (month == 12){
       cout << "The doomsday for month " << month << " is 12." << endl;
       z = 12;
    }

 }



}

void doomsday (int year)
{         //reference day of the week
  int a, b, c , d, e, x;


  a = ((year/100) % 4);
  b = (year % 100);
  c = (b/12);
  d = (b % 12);
  e = (d/4);

  x = ((c + d + e + (5*a) + 2) % 7);

  if (x == 0)
    cout << "The doomsday for " << year << " is Sunday." << endl;
  else if (x == 1)
    cout << "The doomsday for " << year << " is Monday." << endl;
  else if (x == 2)
    cout << "The doomsday for " << year << " is Tuesday." << endl;
  else if (x == 3)
    cout << "The doomsday for " << year << " is Wednesday." << endl;
  else if (x == 4)
    cout << "The doomsday for " << year << " is Thursday." << endl;
  else if (x == 5)
    cout << "The doomsday for " << year << " is Friday." << endl;
  else if (x == 6)
    cout << "The doomsday for " << year << " is Saturday." << endl;
}

void dayoftheweek(int month, int day, int year)
{
 int r;
 cout << "You want to find out what day of the week " << month << "/" << day << "/" << year << " lies on." << endl;
 doomsday(year);
 r = (day - z) + 14;          //offset between the given day and the result of     dayofthemonth function.
 cout << r << endl;
}


int main(){

int year, month, day;


cout << "Enter the year." << endl;
cin >> year;

cout << "Enter the month using numbers 1-12." << endl;
cin >> month;

cout << "Enter the day." << endl;
cin >> day;

dayoftheweek(month, day, year);


cin.get();
return 0;


}
```